# Trying to make a tumblr theme's assets transparent

Tags: html, tumblr

I found a nice free tumblr theme, and used what limited knowledge I have to change the background, but whoever made the theme didn't make any of the icons or assets for the theme transparent, so I have huge black boxes around everything, and while I was able to fix most of them in photoshop, there's one that I just can't seem to get working. Here's all the code I think is relevant:

```
.link .container { padding: 0 0 0 240px; }
    .link .link-wrap { position: relative; width: 590px; min-height: 90px; }
    .link .hand { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 165px; height: 90px; background: {color:Accent} url("http://static.tumblr.com/gpln05e/BgCdi9xSQ/link-hand.png") no-repeat 100% 0; }
    .link h2 { font-size: 200%; margin-right: 165px; background: {color:Accent} url("http://static.tumblr.com/gpln05e/F8chS9xSQ/link-top.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
    .link h2 span { display: block; padding: 35px 0 20px 20px; background: transparent url("http://static.tumblr.com/gpln05e/5GBYS9xSQ/link-bot.png") no-repeat 0 100%; }
    .link h2 a:link, .link h2 a:visited { color: #fff; }
    .link h2 a:hover, .link h2 a:active { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff; }
    .link .content { padding: 0 260px 0 20px; margin-top: 10px; }
    .link .meta { top: 35px; }
```

I just ripped the images I needed straight from the code, and made the parts I need transparent just that, but it doesn't seem to work.

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMZnL.png)

What I think is the issue is that the part you see that is fuchsia is actually the transparent part of the image, which another part of the code is telling to be whatever you set as the accent colour, which I believe is this part:

```
    <meta name="color:Accent" content="#ee3322" />
```

In which case I need a way to change the code so that it changes a certain non-transparent colour to the accent colour, that way all the black I don't want I can make transparent.

Here's a link to a pastebin of the full code if what I provided above isn't enough.

[Pastebin of full code](http://pastebin.com/MadLi17a)

Answer (score 0):

#### Variable Transformations

It is possible to convert a `hex` colour to `rgb` using variable transformations: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations

In this case, prepend the custom variable name with `RGB`.

**Example 1 (Hardcoded Alpha)**

Metatag:

```
<meta name="color:Accent" content="#ee3322" />
```

CSS:

```
.link h2 {background: rgba({RGBcolor:Accent},0.5)}
```

Output:

```
.link h2 {background: rgba(238,51,34,0.5)}
```

**Example 2 (Custom Variable Alpha)**

Metatag:

```
<meta name="color:Accent" content="#ee3322" />
<meta name="text:AccentOpacity" content="0.5" />
```

CSS:

```
.link h2 {background: rgba({RGBcolor:Accent},{text:AccentOpacity})}
```

Output:

```
.link h2 {background: rgba(238,51,34,0.5)}
```

The benefit of **Example 2** is the user of the theme can adjust the alpha / opacity. I called it opacity for simplicity.

Hope that helps.